# The idempotent monad of $\mu$-accessible functors

Tags: ct.category-theory

Freyd and Kelly's paper

> Freyd, Peter J., and G. Max Kelly. "Categories of continuous functors, I." Journal of pure and applied algebra 2.3 (1972): 169-191.

shows that given a certain class of shapes $\Gamma\subset\bf Cat$ the subcategory $[C,D]^\Gamma$ of functors $C \to D$ that commute with $G$-shaped colimits of diagrams $G\to C$, for $G\in\Gamma$ is reflective in $[C,D]$ (am I right?).

What is known about the idempotent monad associated to this reflection, in the special case $\Gamma$ is the class $\mu\text{-}{\sf Filt}$ of $\mu$-filtered categories, for $\mu$ a fixed regular cardinal?

Of course this monad is the inclusion of the reflected functor $rP$ into $[C,D]$, if $r\dashv$ inclusion. But Freyd and Kelly do not build much intuition for this reflector. So, more explicitly, my question is

> What is the action on objects and morphisms of the monad $T_{\mu\text{-}{\sf Filt}} : [C,D]\to [C,D]$ associated to the reflection $[C,D]^\Gamma \hookrightarrow [C,D]$?

You are free to assume that (for example) $D=Set$.

Comment: It's a little funny -- in Thm 5.2.1 of the paper, $C$ is assumed to be small. I don't often think about $\mu$-filtered colimits in small categories. For example, if $\mu$ is at least the number of (isomorphism classes of) objects of $C$, then then $T_{\mu -Filt}$ is the identity monad. If $C = Ind_\mu^{\mu'}(C')$, then $T_{\mu-Filt}$ just replaces a functor with the left Kan extension of its restriction to $C'$. Are you interested in more complicated situations than this?

Comment: In principle, yes, $C$ small and $D=Set$ is enough; but then I'm not able to interpret any more the request that there are $\Gamma$-colimits in $C$ and the functors preserve them; if $\Gamma$ is too big this is too strong a request on $C$!

Comment: Just to be clear: you don't have any choice about $C$ -- it must be small for the Freyd-Kelly results to apply. Although there's at least one case where $C$ need not be small -- if $C = Ind_\mu(C')$, then the reflection exists -- $T_{\mu-Filt}(F) = Lan_{C' \subset C}( F|_{C'})$. The case $C = Ind_\mu^{\mu'}(C')$ (the free cocompletion of $C'$ under $\mu'$-small, $\mu$-filtered colimits) is similar, and _is_ small.

Comment: My gut-feeling about this response is that it's precisely what I wanted. If after a while of thought I'll still be satisfied I'll be glad to accept an extensive answer